# jQuery div hover slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

I have this div here:

```
<div style="
width: 259px; 
height: 201px; 
background-color: #282c2f; 
box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px #000; 
border-radius: 10px; 
border: 2px solid #282c2f;">SHOP</div>
```

That when a user hovers, the grey box needs to slide down into a teal box. So the new color is shown, and a link is ready to be clicked.

It should slide into:

```
<div style="
    width: 259px; 
    height: 201px; 
    background-color: #00e7b4; 
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px #000; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid #282c2f;"><a href="shop.htm">SHOP</div>
```

Is there anything where I can see an effect similar to this working? Perhaps plugin suggestions? Not sure how to start on this.

Very similar to what I am looking for, except the black disappears as it slides out of the div: http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/

Comment: You want the black box to disappear? You can set the opacity to 0 as another option of your animate function.
Edit: do you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/19/

Comment: @DanielSanchez Where would that go exactly? Sorry, really new to jQuery.

Comment: Were you looking for something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/20/

Comment: @DanielSanchez Very close! See the black will be on top of the teal. So when you hover, the black slides down and the teal is exposed. And once that slides down, on top of the teal there is a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish. I haven't tested for browser compatibility, so you may want to do that and play around with it.
Basically just involved adding an additional div, and using slideDown on the new div.

```
<div id="newTarget" style="display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background-color:teal; border: teal solid 1px; position:absolute;">
    <a id="newTargetLink" href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/22/

Comment: Awesome! I had to change the first div to position:absolute and that worked! But now, how would I get the black div to slide up again after the hover is no longer active?

Comment: You can try using mouseenter and mouseout rather than hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/29/

Answer (score 0):

You can chain [animations in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  If I understand you correctly you could do it like this:

```
trigger.hover(function() {
    target.animate({top: 0}).animate({opacity : 0});
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bUcZg/21/